# Get Sharepoint user details for currently logged in user? (SOAP API)

Tags: ios, sharepoint, smartcard

Is there a way to get the results of `UserGroup.GetUserInfo` but without having to specify the user I'm querying for, such as with `UserGroup.GetRolesAndPermissionsForCurrentUser`?

In particular, I'm trying to get the User ID (so that I can tell if a Document is checked out to the currently logged in user, or not). Unfortunately, I am using a SmartCard to provide credentials -- there is no username or password entered for the actual document library -- So I can't use domain\username for `GetUserInfo`, which is how I do it for non-smart card usage.

Additionally, I'm on iOS, so I don't really have any nice SharePoint APIs to use -- everything needs to be available through the 2007/2010 SOAP WebService APIs

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `UserGroup.GetCurrentUserInfo`.
The Sharepoint SOAP documentation can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcusergroup.usergroup.getcurrentuserinfo(v=office.14).aspx.

If you have access to a Sharepoint instance you can check the SOAP envelope and response here:
htttp://your.sharepointserver.com/_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx?op=GetCurrentUserInfo (do not use this URL in the actual request from your app).

Below is an example implementation based on AFNetworking and a sub classed AFHTTPClient.

```
// Get user info for currently signed in user
- (void)currentUserInfoWithSuccessBlock:(void(^)(SharepointCurrentUserResponse *response))successBlock
                              failBlock:(void(^)(NSError *error))failBlock {

  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                    path:@"_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx"
                                              parameters:nil];

  NSString *soapEnvelope =
    @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
    @"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
    @"<soap:Body>"
    @"<GetCurrentUserInfo xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/\" />"
    @"</soap:Body>"
    @"</soap:Envelope>";

  // Set headers
  [request setValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  [request setValue:@"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/GetCurrentUserInfo" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

  // Content length
  NSString *contentLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", soapEnvelope.length];
  [request setValue:contentLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

  // Set body
  [request setHTTPBody:[soapEnvelope dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

  AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseData) {
      NSString *xmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSLog(@"XML response : %@", xmlString);

      // Parse the response
      SharepointCurrentUserResponse *response = ...

      successBlock(reponse);
    }
  } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
      NSLog(@"Get user info failed with reason: %@ status code %d",
            error, operation.response.statusCode);

      failBlock(error);
  }];

  // Que operation
  [self enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
}
```

Comment: Seems like this is only available on 2010, not 2007. Won't work for me, but your answer is great for anyone else who is running 2010+